# AutoCompleteTextView sometime show suggestion but sometime not

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

AutoCompleteAdapter class:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<String> mData;
    private int resourceId;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects) {     
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mData = objects;
        resourceId = textViewResourceId;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        TextView textView;

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, null);

        } 

        textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(mData.get(position));

        System.out.println("getView:" + mData);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter custom_filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults f = new FilterResults();

                ArrayList<String> matchItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (constraint != null){ 
                    for (String item : MainActivity.COUNTRIES){
                        if (item.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){/////if contain the string
                            matchItems.add(item);

                        }
                    }                              
                }
                f.values = matchItems;
                return f;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                ArrayList<String> matchItems = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                mData.clear();
                mData.addAll(matchItems);
                System.out.println("publishResults ===" + mData); //data can be printed out here every time

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        };
        return custom_filter;
    }
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.row, new ArrayList<String>());
         final AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);         
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);  

    }
    public static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
        "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };    
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/abc"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text=""
        android:completionThreshold="1" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black">
        <requestFocus />
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now my list is **"Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"**, if I type "ma", "Germany" will show in drop-down, but when I type one more character "n" to become "man", the drop-down disappear, after that, if I continue type one more character "y" to become "many", "Germany" show again. The drop-down of `AutoCompleteTextView` will show like on and off even the match is found. What's wrong with my code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// try this

**activity_main.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>

**auto_complete_list-item.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

**MainActivity**
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
    public static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
            "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.auto_complete_list_item));

        autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                autoComplete.setText(str);
            }
        });
    }

    private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {
        private  ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence constraint) {
                    final FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (int i =0;i<COUNTRIES.length;i++){
                            if(COUNTRIES[i].toLowerCase().contains(constraint)){
                                matchList.add(COUNTRIES[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        resultList = matchList;
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;

                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost pull off all my hairs. I finally find out the problem. My problem only happens in platform 2.2 but when I tested in platform 4.0, the problem gone. But I still have to support 2.2 and above, so at last I found that after I put in this statement `filterResults.count = resultList.size();`, then it works. How stupid this is... I have read through API doc many time, but it never mention about this...

Comment: what is adapterview here?